# ASP.NET listview changing selected row color

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I want to do is: when I click on the 'view' button, the selected row should be highlighted.

I have googled for few hours but can't really understand what I missed:

```
<tr height="30%">
    <td valign="top">
        <div runat="server" id="area" style="height:300px; overflow:scroll">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Result" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:ListView ID="lv_MessageSubject" runat="server" vertical-align="top" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lv_MessageSubject_SelectedIndexChanged" OnSelectedIndexChanging="lv_MessageSubject_SelectedIndexChanging" DataKeyNames ="MessageID" OnPagePropertiesChanged="lv_MessageSubject_PagePropertiesChanged" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lv_MessageSubject_PagePropertiesChanging" OnItemDataBound="lv_MessageSubject_ItemDataBound">
            <LayoutTemplate>
            <table border="1">
                <tr runat="server">
                    <th runat="server"></th>
                    <th runat="server">Message</th>
                    <th runat="server">Sender</th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td><asp:Button ID="cmd_View" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="View" Height="21px" /></td>
            <td><div runat="server" id="area"><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Message") %>' /></div></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Sender") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager" runat="server" PagedControlID="lv_MessageSubject"
            PageSize="10">
            <Fields>
                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" />
                <asp:NumericPagerField />
                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DataPager>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I was told to use ItemDataBound, even though I don't know how the selected change can trigger ItemDataBound. Here is the code I tried anyway:

```
protected void lv_MessageSubject_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((ListView)sender).SelectedIndex == e.Item.DisplayIndex)
        {
            var ctrl = (HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("area");
            ctrl.Attributes["style"] = "background-color:Navy; color:White; padding:0px;";
        }
    }
```

The result is ItemDataBound didn't trigger when I click on the 'view' button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemDataBound does not sounds like a right idea indeed. Since your button is setup to fire a command, ItemCommand looks more appropriate:

```
<asp:ListView ... OnItemCommand="lv_MessageSubject_ItemCommand"

...

<asp:Button ID="cmd_View" runat="server" CommandName="Highlight"

...

protected void lv_MessageSubject_ItemCommand(Object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Highlight")
    {
        var ctrl = (HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("area");
        ctrl.Attributes["style"] = "background-color:Navy; color:White; padding:0px;";
    }
}
```

Note that event has a different name - "Select" is [special](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) in a sense that it invokes some built-in functionality, you probably should not interfere with that.